# Using Conditional random field for many valued labels

Tags: model, natural-language, conditional-random-field

I want to use the CRF for labeling a corpus of annotated text. Each word in the corpus has its own set of labels. More specifically, the labels are the pronunciations of each word: some words like "bow" or "desert"  has more than one pronunciation. I want to predict the correct pronunciation of each word using CRF. How can i model the problem?